# Can I combine two "keybinds" into one in Openbox?

Tags: openbox

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04 with its default window manager, Openbox. Is there a way to edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to combine the following two 
"keybinds" in the "keyboard" section into one?

```
<!-- Launch gedit -->
<keybind key="W-g">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>gedit</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

and

```
<!-- Undecorate -->
<keybind key="C-S-d">
  <action name="Undecorate"/>
</keybind>
```

In other words, I'd like to open `gedit` without window decorations.

I know I can have the same result by retaining the first keybind as it is and having the following entry in the "applications" section of `lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<application name="gedit" type="normal">
  <decor>no</decor>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to combine two keybinds into one but a better way to express it would be to want to combine two actions under one keybind.

However, in the specific case I described, there is a problem. Let's say I have one text editor, Leafpad, open. And Leafpad is decorated. While Leafpad is in focus, I run:

```
<!-- Launch gedit -->
<keybind key="W-g">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>gedit</command>
  </action>
  <action name="Undecorate"/>
</keybind>
```

What happens is this: Gedit opens but is still decorated but the Leafpad window becomes undecorated.

The explanation was provided by folks [here](http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2013-June/007981.html) and [here](http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2013-June/007984.html). From my understanding of the replies, it appears that Openbox executes both the commands but since Gedit takes a while the second command is executed first (on the active window).

Another point is that Gedit does not have any provision built-in to be launched undecorated by means of `--undecorated` or something equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this topic is very old, but there is such an easy answer to your problem.

In the same configuration file you can also set properties for certain windows under the `applications` tag as such:

```
<application name="gedit">
  <decor>no</decor>
</application>
```

After executing `openbox --reconfigure` all gedit windows should open without window decoration.